# How to add image in input type button

Tags: button, input, printing

I have try more time, But i can't

I have try:

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
```

```html
<div id="printableArea">
<h3>Print area</h3>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print This page" />
</div>
```

I want add a image instead of Print value text.